# hgweb raw view returns the wrong content-type

Tags: python, mercurial, content-type, hgweb

Background: I'm using https://bitbucket.org/mariocesar/django-hgwebproxy/wiki/Home to add a Mercurial browser to a Django site I'm building.

The problem I'm having is: The particular files we're storing in the HG repo are bind zone files and happen to be named `/some/path/somedomain.com` which is causing hgweb to set the content-type to `application/x-msdos-program` (when the content is really `text/plain`) when returning the raw view of the file. The incorrect content-type is causing hgwebproxy to dump the content into the page template, rather than just return it. It does a test like this to skip templating:

```
if response['content-type'].split(';')[0] in ('application/octet-stream', 'text/plain'):
    return response
```

Some posible solutions are of course

1. Rename all the files to .zone (Lame and time consuming)
2. Hack hgwebproxy to pass `application/x-msdos-program` (Lame and dirty)
3. Convince hgweb to use the correct content-type (Awesome! I hope you'll help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hgweb uses mimetypes to detect the mime type of a file.  You might be able to override the ".com" suffix detection by adding a settings file.  See: [mimetypes.knownfiles](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.knownfiles):

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.init()
>>> mimetypes.knownfiles
['/etc/mime.types', '/etc/httpd/mime.types', '/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types', '/etc/apache/mime.types', '/etc/apache2/mime.types', '/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types', '/usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types', '/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types', '/usr/local/etc/mime.types']
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed to get this out the door, so I just modified /etc/mime.types.